# Rename worksheet using cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I have a very basic script that takes a cell value, which is a date. Then renames the tab "day, dd/mm/yyyy".

The script has worked fine renaming sheets with the corresponding dates for weeks, but suddenly has an issues from what appears to be 19/03/2018 onwards. The script suddenly seems to be working with a duplicate, have lost or gained a day somewhere. I suspect I have not explained this very well, but it is driving me insane.

The script is;

```
function renameSheetsByTheContentsOfCellA1onEachSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNumber, sourceSheet, newSheetName;

  // iterate through all sheets in the spreadsheet
  for (sheetNumber = 1; sheetNumber < sourceSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {
    sourceSheet = sourceSheets[sheetNumber];
    // get contents of cell A2
    newSheetName = sourceSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
    // rename sheet
    sourceSheet.setName(Utilities.formatDate(newSheetName, "GMT", "EEEEE, dd/MM/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

Why is the processing going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely passing an invalid date type to the `.formatDate` function ([requires a Date, String, String](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))) depending on how the A2 values in your sheets are formatted. To prevent this, you should convert *newSheetName* back to a date via `new Date()` in your script before passing it to the function. Of note, this shouldn't be a problem if all of your A2 values are properly formatted as dates--you might want to check that (most likely they are formatted as "Plain Text" which makes them a string).

Also, if you want your script to apply to the first sheet as well, you need to start your `for` loop at `0` (due to 0 index numbering). I modified your code to account for these changes below:

```
function renameSheetsByTheContentsOfCellA1onEachSheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNumber, sourceSheet, newSheetName;

  // iterate through all sheets in the spreadsheet
  for (sheetNumber = 0; sheetNumber < sourceSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {
    sourceSheet = sourceSheets[sheetNumber];
    // get contents of cell A2
    newSheetName = new Date(sourceSheet.getRange("A2").getValue());
    // rename sheet
    sourceSheet.setName(Utilities.formatDate(newSheetName, "GMT", "EEEEE, dd/MM/yyyy"));
  }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it is still producing the same error. It seems really weird.